# Overwrite Windows search

Tags: windows, windows-10, search, gui, desktop-customization

I am using a custom search application on my computer. However it's currently only accessible via hotkey which is not as easy as the default Windows search.

From what I know you can literally configure everyone on Windows using some registry entries, therefore my question: Can I somehow configure what happens if I click the Windows "search" icon in the right bottom corner? If yes, how?

It would be already enough to just execute a command instead of opening the search bar.

Comment: “I am using a custom search application on my computer.” - Can you be more specific?

Comment: It's an alternative search application called "Wox". Anyway I know how to start the application, the question is how to bind this start command on the default windows search icon in the taskbar?

Comment: If you search for "windows 10 start menu editor" you will find both registry patches and applications to make the process easier. I would recommend leaving the standard search alone and adding a new entry for your custom search.

Comment: If I add an entry inside the start menu then I could also use the hotkeys. The thing is, I'd like to bind it directly to the current search because it's always visible on the desktop. Or do you mean it's possible to add a custom icon into the taskbar like the search icon? I searched for what you told me but couldn't find any special editors for that (at least on google)